# Baire space using extended metric?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Consider the set $C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ of continuously differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, endowed with the extended $C^1$ norm $\|f\|_{C^1} = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)| + \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f'(x)|$.

If we proceed in the usual way (as if the extended norm were a norm, inducing a metric, inducing a topology), do we get a Baire space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question the answer is yes.

I take it we're talking about an "extended metric", by which I gather we mean a function $d:X\times X\to[0,\infty]$ that satisfies all the axioms for a metric. Assuming that's what we mean, the reason people don't talk about extended metric spaces is that an extended metric space is a metric space. If $d$ is an extended metric on $X$ and we define $$\tilde d(x,y)=\min(1,d(x,y))$$then $\tilde d$ is a *metric* on $X$ that induces the same topology as $d$.

In particular $C^1$ with your extended norm is a complete metric space. Depending on why you care about this it may or may not be important to point out that $C^1$ with this (extended) metric is *not* a topological vector space. Addition is continuous, but scalar multiplication is not. (Say $f_n(t)=t/n$. Then $d(f_n,0)\not\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.)

---

Again, depending on why you're asking the question, it may or may not be a good idea to point out that $C^1(\Bbb R)$ *is* a topological vector space in a natural and useful way that has little to do with that extended norm. Define $$\rho_n(f)=\sup_{|t|\le n}(|f(t)|+|f'(t)|)$$and $$d(f,g)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\min(1,\rho_n(f-g)).$$Then $d$ is a complete metric on $C^1$ making it into a topological vector space. And we have $d(f_n,f)\to0$ if and only if $f_n\to f$ and $f_n'\to f'$ uniformly on compact sets, showing that this topology captures the natural notion of convergence in $C^1$.

Comment: Thanks you.  Two small things.  First, I think there is a typo: "max" should be "min", right?  Second, when you say "$C^1$ with your extended norm is a complete metric space,"  am I right that part of the reason this is correct that there is a metric (vs. extended metric) induced by the extended norm (even though $\|f-g\|_{C^1}$ itself is not a metric)?  In any case, my interest is in thinking about residual subsets of $C^1$ under the "natural" topology..

Comment: I mean that if you define $d(f,g)=\min(1,||f-g||)$ then $d$ is a complete metric on $C^1$. _But_ you say you're interested in the "natural" topology; this metric has little to do with what seems to me to be the natural topology...

Comment: Thank you. Could  you elaborate on the last point?  If we were talking about $C^1$ functions on a compact set, the topology induced by $\| \cdot \|_{C^1}$ is what I took to be the natural topology.  Is that incorrect?  What is the natural topology without the compact domain?

Comment: Yes, if we were talking about a compact set that norm would give the natural topology. On $\Bbb R$ what most people would call the natural topology is the topology of uniform convergence (for $f$ and $f'$) _on compact sets_. As in my answer, starting with the word "Again"...